# How to make a synchronous request inside a completion block asynchronous

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

I'm currently using a completion block to be able to check if there is a connection to the server using the following code, but you can definitely tell it hangs the UI because it's synchronous. However, by trying to use dispatch_async to wrap it, you can't get a correct returned boolean from inside the asynchronous block (dispatch code omitted).

Any pointers on how I would go about fixing this?

Code:

```
typedef void(^connection)(BOOL);

- (void)checkInternet:(connection)block
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

    //[request setTimeoutInterval:3.0];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                      returningResponse:&response error:NULL];

    block(([response statusCode] == 200) ? YES : NO);
}

- (void)theMethod
{
    [self checkInternet:^(BOOL internet)
     {
         if (internet)
         {
             NSLog(@"Internet");
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"No internet");
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this, but as you are already using `sendSynchronousRequest` why not just use `sendAsynchronousRequest`

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:
 ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
   block([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] == 200);
 }
];
```

Comment: Sometimes we over complicate things

Answer (score 0):

You could just use AFNetworkings Reachability support: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#network-reachability-manager

Comment: Because it's costly. It' better to check for the connection only when you need to instead of always have it monitoring for flags.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
- (void)checkInternet:(connection)block
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:NULL];
        block(([response statusCode] == 200) ? YES : NO);
    });
}
```

Comment: @troop231: are you sure about that ? because the whole code is under the dispatch_async, so probably it should work. Remove the gcd from method body and check what happens when you call the method like: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{ [self checkInternet:^(BOOL internet)
     {
         if (internet)
         {
             NSLog(@"Internet");
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"No internet");
         }
     }]; });

Comment: Oh, the code works fine without the GCD wrapper, it's making it asynch is the problem not getting the correct bool outside of the block

Comment: Its worth noting that inside of the gcd body that the value returned is correct, the problem is it doesnt send the right boolean to the completion block